# JSON массив в контексте SQL запроса Node JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js

Доброго времени суток. Имеется некий массив.

```js
[
{car: mazda, type: kabriolet, color: red, rider: whore};
{car: BMW, type: sedan, color: black, rider: big boss};
]
```

Используя этот массив для заполнения базы данных, сталкиваюсь с трудностью.
Трудность в следующем. В таблице нужны такие свойства объектов, как `car` и `rider`. Но залетают все свойства, что возвращает сервер. Отсюда ошибка, тк таблица `carview` была создана только со столбцами `car` и `rider`.

SQL запрос выглядит так:

```js
    var query = connection.query('insert into carview set ?', aboutcar[i], function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
      }
      console.error(result);
    });
```

Получается только в том случае, если я удаляю с помощью оператора `delete` ненужные мне свойства объектов. Но вычитал на хабре, что подобный способ вызывает утечку, да и код становится здоровым из-за этих `delete`. Думаю, что ответ кроется в использовании оператора `INSERT`. Помогите направить на путь истинный.

Comment: Если "что-то вычитали", прикладывайте ссылку на то, где вычитали: скорее всего это старый и давно починенный баг, и вы зря боитесь. И подумайте, зачем слать в базу лишние данные, если их можно отрезать заранее.

Comment: [https://habrahabr.ru/post/150723/] решение как у него не работает.  В том то и дело, что лишние данные мне не нужны. Для этого и режу их delete'ом.

Comment: Получается, если delete'ов у меня штук 20 в этом нет ничего страшного?

Comment: А вы прикиньте теоретически, чем могут быть лучше другие варианты.

Comment: Хм. Разве что только если оператор INSERT поддерживает выборку по нужным свойствам. Код станет короче.

Comment: Ценой большего трафика на канале с базой. (фактически это умеет select в insert: это потребует передать ненужные данные в запросе) А код по сравнению с циклом delete'ов не особо-то короче. Стоит оно того? Решайте.

Comment: Спасибо. Оставлю тогда delete'ы.